# Scala Recursion as per list contents

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm attempting to do a method of an object x times, as per the contents of, say:

```
val obstacles = Vector[Obstacle](list...)
```

What I'm doing currently is just suffixing all out (where `location`s are of type, say `Location`):

```
val background: Pic = rectangle
background.place(obstacle1.shape, obstacle1.location)
          .place(obstacle2.shape, obstacle2.location)
          .place(shape3Pic, new Location(location3))
          .place(shape4Pic, new Location(location4))...
```

..which I tried to do with `map`:

```
obstacles.map(o => background.place(o.shape, o.location))
```

..however this then of course only returns a `Vector[Obstacle]`, not the original `background: Pic` with the "additions", and will **not** work with the `shape3Pic: Pic` and `shape4Pic: Pic`, as they are not `Obstacle`.

Apparently this can be done in recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do it without recursion using `foldLeft`

```
shapes.foldLeft(background)((r,c) => r.place(c))
```

Or even shorter

```
shapes.foldLeft(background)(_ place _)
```

Comment: Switched answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Background.place takes only Shape object, it could be as follows:

```
trait Shape { }

trait Background {
  def place(shape: Shape): Background
}

@tailrec
def placeRecursive(shapes: Vector[Shape], background: Background): Background = {
  shapes match {
    case shape +: rest =>
      placeRecursive(rest, background.place(shape))
    case _ =>
      background
  }
}
```

Comment: Scratch my comments. I think this is solved. I'll put it on hold at least.